# OpenCart - Как подключить модальное окно к разным языкам?

Tags: opencart, локализация

**Создал отдельное всплывающее окно:**

```
<div class="form-group required">




  <div id="myModalBox" class="modal fade" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" style="display: flex !important;justify-content: center;align-items: center;position: width:100%">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="margin: 0px auto;">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!-- Заголовок модального окна -->
      <div class="modal-header">

        <h4 class="modal-title">Terms & Conditions</h4>
      </div>
      <!-- Основное содержимое модального окна -->
      <div style="max-height:400px;overflow:auto;" class="modal-body">

<p>text</p>

      </div>
      <!-- Футер модального окна -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="butt-wrap" style="position: relative;height: 100%;display:none;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Agree</button>
        <input id="agree-terms" type="checkbox" title="Accept rules" style="position: absolute;width: 100%;height: 100%;margin: 0;opacity: 0;top: 0;left: 0;" class="control-label" for="input-payment-rules" required><a href="http://bmg-officeworld.com/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=5" target="_blank"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="butt-wrap" style="position: relative;height: 100%;display:none;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://bmg-officeworld.com'">Cancel</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Скрипт, вызывающий модальное окно после загрузки страницы -->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {


    $("#myModalBox").modal('show');
     $(function(){
 $('.modal-body').scroll(function() {
 if($('.modal-body').scrollTop() >= 595) {
 $('.butt-wrap').css('display', 'inline-block');  
 }

 });
}); 


      $("#agree-terms").click(function(){
      $("#myModalBox").modal('hide');
      });

  });
</script>
```

Но как привязать это модальное окно к языкам? То есть, при посещении англ.версии сайта - один текст, при посещении русской версии сайта - другой текст? Как добавить строчку - я знаю. А большой объём текста как добавить? Так-же само? Регистрировать переменную и в неё весь текст прописывать? Но как быть тогда с оформлением?

Движок: OpenCart 2.3

Answer (score 0):

В контроллере того файла представления, в котором размещаете попап, дописываете вывод языковых переменных. Которые до того прописываете в файлах локализации данного контроллера. В попапе выводите как и везде. Всё как обычно.

Comment: Глупый вопрос... а что это за папка попап? Можете подсказать путь?

Comment: попап - всплывающее окно. Где-то же код попапа вы прописали, в каком-то .tpl файле? А у этого файла есть контроллер, файл .php  в папке  catalog/controller, обычно с таким же названием что и у .tpl файла. В этом контроллере подключаются переводы через $this->load->language('папка/файл')

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать!